# New and stuck on IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, indentation

I'm new to Python and Programming in general. I'm trying to get a head start for College come Summer Term. I'm trying to learn from this beginner's book and it cites the following code exactly as I'm putting it... I tried changing the space indent every which way but I still get this message. I understand I'm probably missing something here but I would appreciate the advice as to how I should proceed.

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 17:26:49) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]


  >>> # Ghost Game
   ... from random import randint
   >>> print('Ghost Game')
   Ghost Game
   >>> feeling_brave = True
   >>> score = 0
   >>> while feeling_brave:
   ... ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
    File "<stdin>", line 2
    ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
             ^
   IndentationError: expected an indented block
    >>> ghost_door= randint(1, 3)
    >>> while feeling_brave:
    ... ghost_door= randint(1, 3)
    File "<stdin>", line 2
    ghost_door= randint(1, 3)
             ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>> while feeling_brave:
... ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
             ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
    >>> while feeling_brave:
    ... ghost_door = randint(1,3)
    File "<stdin>", line 2
       ghost_door = randint(1,3)
             ^
   IndentationError: expected an indented block
   >>> while feeling_brave:
   ... ghost_door =randint(1,3)
     File "<stdin>", line 2
    ghost_door =randint(1,3)
```

Comment: Sounds self explanatory, fix your indentations (if you don't know how, google will know)

Comment: all you need to do is indent `ghost_door`. just like the error says to do

Comment: So, as I understand it, I indent before the 'g' then? I'm sorry, I'm still trying to understand the layout..

Comment: @Joseph this might help you -- it's the style guide for python code https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Much appreciated Sterling.

Answer (score 0):

After a "while" statement, the interpreter shows you "...". You must the provide the indentation by typing four spaces at the start of your next line.

Comment: Why four spaces?

Comment: @TZHX because that is the equivalent of an indent.

Comment: So is a single space. Or a tab.

Comment: Usually, a tab is as long as four spaces, but yes, any space can be an indent, just as long as it stays consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Add an indent by pressing [TAB] in front of your existing indentation on the line

```
... ghost_door = randint(1,3)
```

Currently, you have got:

```
while feeling_brave:
    ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
```

You have not got the "statements" for the loop as an indent, so the interpreter treats it as two consecutive commands. However, having

```
while feeling_brave:
    ghost_door = randint(1, 3)
```

tells the interpreter to execute your second line while the loop is running.

Comment: Indent your code formatting by four spaces, rather than using bsckticks, to preserve new lines.

Comment: @TZHX What do you mean by preserve new lines?

Comment: If you look at your answer, does the code look how you expected it to?

Comment: Well, no. Good point. Thanks for the heads up ;)